# Episerver- Link a block using the Insert/Edit link of a Rich Text Block editor?

Tags: episerver

I have an page with multiple blocks having a structure as follows:

1-  RichText Editor Block: This contains multiple links as given below that are basically linked to a section within the same page using Insert/Edit link:
[image]

2-  Accordion Block: As the name say ,this being an accordion ,I am displaying this as collapsed on initial page load.
[image]
I am trying to link the item from 1(richtext editor block) to 2(accordion block) so that when link  1 is selected ,it should move the page section to not just 2 but also open it. The collapsing/expanding can be achieved using .js script. The linking is the part that I am unsure of.

Issue: Insert Edit/Link in 1 is a link collection so using the Page property the page is self linked but I am unable to link the accordion block
[image]
So is there a way to link a block using the Insert/Edit link or I have to go via a custom implementation?
Also, what how does Anchor property in linkcollection works?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: There's no built-in feature for inserting an anchor link to a specific block within the TinyMCE editor.